# Visual Studio entity framework error (init.ps1 cannot be loaded)

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I worked with visual studio community edition for about 2 months without a problem. Suddenly it gives me an error message on the package manager console by saying entity framework init.ps1 cannot be loaded. I dont know why suddenly this error pops up. I tried every solution which have been listed on the internet but still the problem remains. I reinstall VS but still the same error is there.

this is the error:

"& : File C:\Users\Wiji\Desktop\Queries\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
At line:1 char:45
+ ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users\Wiji\Desktop\Queries\packages\EntityFramework.6 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess"

Im stucked with this error and cannot continue development because package manager console cannot run commands related to EF.

Please give me a solution to overcome this.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and was able to resolve it by deleting the Packages folder from the solution entirely. This forced Visual Studio to rebuild all the packages and the error disappeared, allowing for normal EF commands in the PM.